# data function grouped item in a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm using `Postgresql` to write a query which for every day calculate the sum of diff values and get unit price from other table `il_costs`, what I try to achieve with a subquery. Below whole query:

```
SELECT date(read.readed_at), 
       SUM(read.diff), 
       (SELECT water_unit 
        FROM il_costs 
        WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date(read.readed_at)) 
          AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date(read.readed_at))) 
FROM il_communicators_readings read 
GROUP BY date(read.readed_at) 
ORDER BY date(read.readed_at) ASC;
```

I'm getting error about ungrouped column, but I'm using `date(read.readed_at)` also in grouped function:

```
ERROR: subquery uses ungrouped column "read.readed_at" from outer query
LINE 1: ...(MONTH FROM created_at) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date(read.reade...
```

Comment: General GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using your query as a subquery and perform the correlated subquery in the outer query:

```
SELECT mydate, s_diff,
       (SELECT water_unit 
        FROM il_costs 
        WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM mydate) 
          AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM mydate)) 
FROM (
  SELECT date(read.readed_at) AS mydate, 
         SUM(read.diff) as s_diff
  FROM il_communicators_readings read 
  GROUP BY date(read.readed_at) ) AS t
ORDER BY mydate ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not read.readed_at, it's the subquery not in the group by. and i don't think it's a good idea to use subquery like this.

Try this:

```
SELECT date(read.readed_at), 
   SUM(read.diff), 
   costs.water_unit
FROM il_communicators_readings read 
Left Join il_costs costs
ON EXTRACT(MONTH FROM costs.created_at) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date(read.readed_at)) 
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM costs.created_at) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date(read.readed_at))
GROUP BY date(read.readed_at),costs.water_unit
ORDER BY date(read.readed_at) ASC;
```